# Get width of drawText in GraphicsMagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I have a variable width word that I would like to center in a fixed sized box.  How can I calculate the width of the text so that I know how far the left offset should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify your programming language so I am assuming you are using C.

You can determine the width with the MagickQueryFontMetrics methods (http://www.graphicsmagick.org/wand/magick_wand.html#magickqueryfontmetrics) this returns a double array containing the following information:

- 0 character width
- 1 character height
- 2 ascender
- 3 descender
- 4 text width
- 5 text height
- 6 maximum horizontal advance

Or if you could use use the GetTypeMetrics method that gives you the information in a nice struct:

- *GetTypeMetrics(Image *image,const DrawInfo *draw_info, TypeMetric *metrics)*